# The "openssl genrsa" command only generates a private key?

Tags: rsa, keys, openssl

The command :

```
openssl genrsa -out RootCA.key 4096
```

generates a single file named RootCA.key. When I open the file, it only contains the **private** key.

Then the next command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1000 -key RootCA.key -out RootCA.crt
```

Generates a certificate , named RootCA.crt containing the Root's **public** key.

How can the second command generate a public key, given ONLY the private key?
 Isn't the whole value of cryptography depends on the impossibility of generating one key from another in a key pair ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can the second command generate a public key, given ONLY the
> private key?

It will probably use the public key encoded in the private key datastructure. As per [RFC 3447 / PKCS1 (v2.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.2) the `RSAPrivateKey`  should contain:

> ```
> RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
>           version           Version,
>           modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
>           publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
>           privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
>           prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
>           prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
>           exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
>           exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
>           coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
>           otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
>       }
> ```

which contains a public key $(n,e)$ as well as the private key $(n,d)$ and some other useful information.

> Isn't the whole value of cryptography depends on the impossibility of
> generating one key from another in a key pair?

No. Generating the public key from the private key is fine. Generating the private key from the public key is not. And in fact with RSA, it *can* be hard to recover the public key from the private key, *if* you only store the private exponent $d$ and the public modulus $n$ (which is the bare minimum needed for private-key operations) *and* if you pick the public exponent $e$ not to be the standard $65537=2^{16}+1$ but some random large integer.

On the other hand, for DSA and ECDSA, the private key is only an integer $d$ and the public key is $g^d$ for some fixed $g$ which is needed for private key operations. So recovering the public key from the private key is *always* and *inevitably* possible with (EC)DSA.